# TreeViewItem MVVM IsSelected in Xaml doesn't send value to View-Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeviewitem

I have a problem with IsSelected property. It doesn't send values from view to view-model. I posted my code below
ViewModel:

```
public class Viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> seznam;
    public ObservableCollection<int> Seznam
    {
        get { return seznam; }
        set
        {
            seznam = value;
        }
    }

    public Viewmodel()
    {
        Seznam = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Seznam.Add(i);
        }
    }

    bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

View:

```
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Seznam}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

It still doesn't stop at breakpoint that I put on get { return isSelected; }

Comment: Any binding errors while you debug?

Comment: Does your view model implement INotifyPropertyChnaged? Please show the signature of your viewmodel

Comment: There are no binding errors.

Comment: yes, I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Just to clarify, you do see items in the TreeView, and if you set IsSelected in the view model item, the appropriate TreeViewItem gets selected? It's just the direction view to view model which doesn't work?

Comment: I can see the items, items get selected when I click on them, it's just the feedback if the item is selected or not that doesn't work.

Comment: And they also get selected when you set the IsSelected property in the view model item?

Comment: My IsSelected property gets set only in the beginning, and yes.. the items get selected.

Comment: The code you show would work fine. I've written a test program from scratch that uses the same basic logic, and it works as expected. So the problem is somewhere in the code you didn't share. You need to fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your updated post, it is clear that you haven't implemented your view models correctly. In particular, your `TreeView.ItemsSource` is bound to the `Seznam` property of your only view model. This is a collection of `int` values.

This means that the data context for each item container in the `TreeView`, where you attempt to bind to the `IsSelected` property, is an `int` value. And of course, `int` values don't even have an `IsSelected` property.

(By the way, I am skeptical about [your claim that *"There are no binding errors"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513864/treeviewitem-mvvm-isselected-in-xaml-doesnt-send-value-to-view-model/44533457#comment76020358_44513864). If you looked at the debug output, you certainly should have seen a binding error, where attempting to bind to the non-existent `IsSelected` property.)

And think about this for a moment: supposing the item container did manage to bind to the `Viewmodel.IsSelected` property. How many item containers do you think there are? And how many instances of `Viewmodel` do you think there are? You *should* believe that there are many item containers, i.e. one for each item in your collection. And that there is just one instance of `Viewmodel`. So, how would all those items' selection state even map to the single `Viewmodel.IsSelected` property?

The right way to do this would be to create a separate view model object for the collection, with a property for your `int` value, as well as properties for the `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` states (since you originally had mentioned wanting both).

Here is the example I wrote earlier just to prove to myself that the usual approach would work as expected. You should not have any trouble adapting it to suit your needs…

**Per-item view model:**

```
class TreeItemViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>();

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _isSelected, value, _OnBoolPropertyChanged); }
    }

    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _isExpanded, value, _OnBoolPropertyChanged); }
    }

    private void _OnBoolPropertyChanged(bool obj)
    {
        _RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullText));
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _text, value, _OnTextChanged); }
    }

    private void _OnTextChanged(string obj)
    {
        _RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullText));
    }

    public string FullText
    {
        get { return $"{Text} (IsSelected: {IsSelected}, IsExpanded: {IsExpanded})"; }
    }
}
```

**Main view model for window:**

```
class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>();

    public ICommand ClearSelection { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ClearSelection = new ClearSelectionCommand(this);
    }

    class ClearSelectionCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly MainViewModel _parent;

        public ClearSelectionCommand(MainViewModel parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

#pragma warning disable 67
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
#pragma warning restore 67

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _parent._ClearSelection();
        }
    }

    private void _ClearSelection()
    {
        _ClearSelection(Items);
    }

    private static void _ClearSelection(IEnumerable<TreeItemViewModel> collection)
    {
        foreach (TreeItemViewModel item in collection)
        {
            _ClearSelection(item.Items);
            item.IsSelected = false;
            item.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML for window:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO44513864TreeViewIsSelected.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO44513864TreeViewIsSelected"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:MainViewModel>
      <l:MainViewModel.Items>
        <l:TreeItemViewModel Text="One">
          <l:TreeItemViewModel.Items>
            <l:TreeItemViewModel Text="One A"/>
            <l:TreeItemViewModel Text="One B"/>
          </l:TreeItemViewModel.Items>
        </l:TreeItemViewModel>
        <l:TreeItemViewModel Text="Two"/>
        <l:TreeItemViewModel Text="Three"/>
      </l:MainViewModel.Items>
    </l:MainViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Clear Selection" Command="{Binding ClearSelection}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1">
      <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <p:Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
          <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </p:Style>
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="l:TreeItemViewModel"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullText}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And for completeness…

**The boilerplate base class for `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation:**

```
class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        _RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void _RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: First and second paragraph of your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the IsSelected on every node in the tree, use the TreeView.SelectedItem on the TreeView itself. From here you can bind, but the property is readonly.